# How to get a-href from specific place from Page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have problem with getting a-href from a page. My cod looks like:

```
string url ="" // specifed URL
var doc = DownloadPage(url);
var categoryDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='category-nav']//ul//a[@href]");
```

[image: JSS]

I want to get all <  li > a-href's. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript:

`document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');`

And I think your question changed so:
`document.querySelectorAll('li > a[href]');`

This would only select `a[href]`s that are immediate children of an `<li>`

Comment: I want from <div class ="root-level-nav"> get all a href-s in < li > 's

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with the html-agility-pack. In JS, you could find that node using `document.getElementsByClassName('root-level-nav')[0]` and then on *that* object run your `querySelectorall()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string url ="" // specifed URL
    var doc = DownloadPage(url);
    var categoryDivs = doc.DocumentNode
                        .Descendants( "ul" )
                        .Where(ul => ul.HasClass("category-nav"));
```

Now to get all ahrefs which are childrens/grandchildrens of this  do this:

```
    var link = categoryDivs
              .Descendants("a");
```

**And from there:**
you can get:

```
string hrefValue = link[0]?.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Comment: You need to do a foreach to get all them href links though.

Comment: My var categoryDivs couldn't find class "category-nav".
I have no idea how to get there

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that category part is not working either. I have updated the code.

Comment: glad that it helped. Please accept this as answer which will definitely help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can simply do: `$("li > a[href]")`